# Compare csv files (results) in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am new to Jmeter, I am working with JDBC.
I am running a sampler which consists of 3 jdbc requests and I am storing output of complete sampler in CSV file.
trying to compare the previous result file with current results.
Can anyone help me how to do it , Do I need to use any specific plugin to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give example of what you comparing?

Comment: I am saving the responses of queries in a csv file and when I run the test second time then those results should compare with saved file

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare 2 files you could use [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion).

1. Add JSR223 Assertion somewhere to your Test Plan (normally it should go as a child of a [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers))
2. Make sure you have `groovy` as a language and `Cache compiled script if available` box checked
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   boolean filesEqual = FileUtils.contentEquals(new File('/path/to/file1'), new File('/path/to/file2'))

   if (!filesEqual) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Files are not equal');
   }
   ```

If files content will be different the JSR223 Assertion will fail parent Sampler (or Samplers, according to the [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules))

References:

- [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class reference
- [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) class reference
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks,
is there any way to find out the difference between two result files in Jmeter ?